# Magento Payment methods depending on fields Company and VAT ID

Tags: magento

We would like Magento to only display the payment method "Purchase order" when the fields "Company name" and "Taxvat" are filled out on the Magento checkout page. (so that only businesses can purchase and pay afterwards)

We use Firecheckout, but that doesn't matter because it requests the payment methods every time something changes in the address (like company name).

So the modification has to be made somewhere in the function $methods = $this->getMethods(). But where and how to do it? I know that the payment methods can by default be dependend on the country entered on the same page, so it should be possible that it's also dependend on the Company and VAT fields.

Thanks for your help guys!